# Valid Email Addresses are not allowed to submit

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5.2

below is my code for email validation -

```
UserViewModel.cs

[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address")]       
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

Edit.cshtml

<div class='form-group'>
    @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.EmailAddress):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.EmailAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
</div>

UserController.cs

if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   //Show error to user
}
//Update user details
```

I looked at this wiki page for valid email addresses - 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

and when I tried submitting my form for following email addresses -

```
"much.more unusual"@example.com
"very.unusual.@.unusual.com"@example.com
"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com
admin@mailserver1
"()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org
" "@example.org
üñîçøðé@example.com
üñîçøðé@üñîçøðé.com
```

All above email addresses fail at client-side validation apart from `admin@mailserver1`, which fails at server-side validation.

Questions -

- Why HTML5/MVC email address validation doesn't pass these valid email addresses.
- Is there any web link to list HTML5 email validation rules?
- Is there any web link to list MVC email validation rules?

Thank you!

Comment: You can find the regex used in asp.net MVC for email validation [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/EmailAddressAttribute.cs), it seems to validate all of the email address you've listed, so this is a strange issue...

Comment: As for the client-side validation - I believe most of those cases will fail - see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html - the regex used to validate email is /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/

Comment: By the way, I can't replicate your issue without html5 email attribute `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { type = "email" })`

Comment: I am using IE10 and it works fine for me without setting type explicitly. (One can also use EditorFor which adds this attribute automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For html5 client-side validation - I believe most of those cases will fail - see [w3c's email specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/input.email.html#input.email.attrs.value.single) - the regex used to validate email is:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

All the one's listed apart form `admin@mailserver1` will fail this regex match test.

You can find the regex used in asp.net MVC for email validation in the [ASP.NET MVC github repo](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/1ccfcdfc11da19a88f6efc6f512e67b68fa04fec/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/EmailAddressAttribute.cs)
From the RegEx tests that I've performed, it seems to accept all those email addresses as valid apart from `admin@mailserver1`

Comment: Thanks for the links. Depending on above findings, I feel I should take the Regex from MVC link and add it to my client side validation. What do you suggest?

Comment: If you really need to have it the way ASP.NET does the email validation - then yes - I don't see the issue at all with using a well tested RegEx. http://jsfiddle.net/andyw_/n8c0ma44/2/

Comment: Although, I would do it via JS because I'm not sure if html5 pattern attribute support flags required

Comment: Okay.. Do you have any idea why MVC validation doesn't allow admin@mailserver1 ?

Comment: Most likely because it's been built with the assumption that email addresses require a top-level domain rather than a local domain i.e. myname@company. If you're wondering about why the regex itself does not allow it, it's a fairly big regex to analyse - I'm not a huge fan of analysing huge regex :) I personally write a simple parser instead of regex when it reaches a certain length.

Comment: Thanks for replying to all my questions. They have really helped :-) FYI, I have kept it standard - with HTML5 client side and MVC server side validation.